# How to get a Header from xls/xlsx in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

How to get only header values from the xls/xlsx file in JavaScript or jQuery without parsing the whole file?. `XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });`   taking too much time for parsing. But I need only headers on browser side. I'll do the rest on server-side. Thank you.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.7/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xls/0.7.4-a/xls.core.min.js"></script> `

Comment: This both library I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "your excel file.xlsx";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function(e) {
  var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
  var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) {
    arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  }
  var bstr = arr.join("");
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
  var t = workbook.SheetNames;
}
oReq.send();
```

Comment: like what @YangshunTay ?

Comment: what you say @YangshunTay now ?? Perfect or still some change ?

Comment: Now it's perfect

Comment: @Krunal Shah: And why exactly do you think, that this will be better than using directly the `data` array gotten from `var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);` as shown in [js-xlsx demos](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/tree/master/demos/xhr#xmlhttprequest)?